# What is necessary to init ASPxGridView controls?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview, devexpress-mvc

i tried to dynamicaly load GridView on the existing page from server. However, when I get the html from the server and insert it into the element, grid appears, but some actions are not available on it (for example drag and drop on columns, filters and so on). Moreover, i have a callback on init event and controls init event, but they dont invoke. Recently, i have loaded gridview with full page and all was good. On support center i found that i need to use `ASPx.Evt.DispatchEvent(window, "load");` after insert gridview in my page, but there isnt any explanation about this. Currently, after i have added this piece of code and most of functionality works well and client side events fired, but some are still broken, for example `GridView.PerformCallback();`. What else i need to do to init controls on my gridview?

Origin code about 'load' event in devexpress support center
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T489045/how-to-determine-if-scripts-are-loaded

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned ticket refers to the MVC Extensions product, not the WebForms.

In the meantime, why do you need to render the HTML and add it to the DOM and initialize manually? It is not a good practice for the server-side controls (i.e., when the client-side counterpart should be properly processed).

If you need to add the DevExpress ASP.NET WebForms control dynamically, consider using, for example, [ASPxCallbackPanel](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-controls-within-aspxcallbackpanel-on-callbacks-e4113).